# Android Camera2 executable failed to get frames

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-camera2

I have one Camera2 NDK code to open the camera and get images.

The code work fine via Android Application/Service, but if I compile and run it as executable the camera opened but I don't get any frames.

Any idea? someone succeeded to do it?

---

NOTE

1. I create my own AImageReader via "AImageReader_new"
2. I create my own ANativeWindow via "AImageReader_getWindow"

---

NOTE2 (ADDED)

The calls is a little different

For Android Application/Service the calls like:

```
public void onCreate() {
       JNIBridge.startPreview(null);
}
public void onDestroy() {
       JNIBridge.stopPreview();
}
```

For the executable:

```
int main()
{
Java_com_y30_nativecamera2_JNIBridge_startPreview(nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);

for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
}

Java_com_y30_nativecamera2_JNIBridge_stopPreview(nullptr, nullptr);

return 0;
}
```

---

UPDATE

I tested it again on multi Android devices.

S8/S9+ (With Andorid 8.0.0) it's reproduce.("ACameraManager_openCamera" status is OK, but I don't get any frames)

Pixel (With Android 9) the method "ACameraManager_openCamera" failed.

```
10-09 10:45:04.933   933  1592 I CameraService: CameraService::connect call (PID -1 "", camera ID 0) for HAL version default and Camera API version 2
10-09 10:45:04.933   933  1592 W ServiceManager: Permission failure: android.permission.CAMERA from uid=2000 pid=19606
10-09 10:45:04.933   933  1592 E CameraService: Permission Denial: can't use the camera pid=19606, uid=2000
10-09 10:45:04.933 19606 19606 E ACameraManager: openCamera: connect camera device failed: Status(-8): '1: validateClientPermissionsLocked:906: Caller "" (PID 2000, UID 19606) cannot open camera "0" without camera permission'
```

---

UPDATE2

I tested it also with msm8996 EVB (With Android 7.1.1):

(1) I get permission issue like the Pixel2.

(2) I ran it with su and the permission issue fixed (the camera opened) but I already don't get any images.

Comment: Not sure if this is helpful: https://www.sisik.eu/blog/android/ndk/camera but your question as written doesn't provide enough detail as to what is going wrong as you state `code work fine via Android Application/Service, but if I compile and run it as executable` doesn't make much sense in a Android context. What executable?

Comment: Please see: https://corochann.com/build-executable-file-with-android-ndk-after-lollipop-android-api-21-388.html

Comment: Error `cannot open camera "0" without camera permission` sounds pretty clear - seems like you didn't acquire permissions to open camera.

Comment: @DmitriiZ. you completely right on the Pixel2 (with Android 9) case. but what about the other devices? (I don't get any log like this in the other devices...)

Comment: @DmitriiZ. also maybe It's related to Android 9?

Comment: Making executables is not an android way of programming, so it is hard to tell what exactly is wrong. For example, it could be that your main() is executed as main thread & `sleep_for` is basically blocking all UI stuff, so essentially your program startspreview, doesn't allow it to draw and stops it. It could also be caused by the missing android app lifecycle pipeline items. Without further explanation of *WHY* do you need it to be executable it is very hard to help you.

Comment: @DmitriiZ."WHY do you need it to be executable" - deeper understanding/curiosity...

Comment: @DmitriiZ. "It could also be caused by the missing android app lifecycle pipeline items" - Why? I want to understand the exact problem.

Comment: @DmitriiZ." it could be that your main() is executed as main thread & sleep_for is basically blocking all UI stuff" - to the executable running no have any UI. but  maybe it's related to something with the sleep (Although he probably
wakes up between the sleeps...).

Comment: Your question is too broad for this site. You should probably read a book or an article about how android works. You can see what is `on-topic` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @DmitriiZ."You should probably read a book or an article about how android works" - sorry but I work a lot of with Android. I'm looking for an answer, not a general statement. Thanks!

Comment: @DmitriiZ. "Your question is too broad for this site" - I think not. my directions is maybe it's related to the surface or to the sleep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not seen your code. From your description, you have done everything right. If you add the following, it should work.

```
#include <binder/ProcessState.h>

...
main()
{
...
    android::ProcessState::self()->startThreadPool();
...
    Camera open, AImageReader_new, etc ...
...
    Close Camera
...
}
```

Also add libbinder to Android.mk LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES.

Comment: You right! tested and works with Samsung S8/S9+ (Android 8).

Comment: Right. NDK does not have binder. Since you're building inside AOSP, there is no problem using binder APIs. If you wish to use pure NDK, you have to wait for a future Android version when ABinderProcess_startThreadPool() will be supported.

Answer (score -1):

In general, the NDK does not support Android shell executables, so its use is probably blocked by your devices SELinux policy in some way.

Comment: (1) NDK is support shell executables! you can compile it with "include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)", push it to "/data/local/tmp/" and run it.

Comment: (2) I think that the SELinux is not the problem. a. I compare the logs and don't see any SELinux logs [cat log.log | grep 'avc:']. (2) The code is same! I don't try to open something like "/dev/videoX" ...

Comment: (3) The camera opened. (maybe with the surface?)

Comment: "include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)" is not an NDK build command, it's part of the Android platform build, which is not the NDK (https://developer.android.com/ndk/) which uses Android Studio or cmake (or ndk-build).   Executables built in the Android platform build aren't supported by the NDK or SDK in any direct way; some APIs may work and others might not.

Comment: (1) "is not an NDK build command" - it's part of normal ndk-build (you can see corochann.com/… ) (2) "some APIs may work and others might not" - you right because of to the exe a. not have app context (in this api you not need it) b. permissions - compared to App (up to Android 9 I don't see any problem with it...) c. UI api's. (3) "Android Studio or cmake (or ndk-build)" - Android Studio use gradle that use cmake or ndk-build.

Comment: NOTE: I have a long experience with Android camera private API cpp code. and in past I succeeded to get images via executable with new camera implementations. (with "BufferQueue::createBufferQueue and ConsumerBase::FrameAvailableListener")

Comment: I ran it on msm8996 EVB (With Android 7.1.1) and get also permission problem like the Pixel2. but if if I run it as su the permission issue solve, and the problem of getting images is already exists.