# How to access camera from natively compiled c++ binary in Android

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, adb, android-camera2

I have been experimenting to access the camera with Android C++ native API. But instead of including the binary inside an APK, I just compiled the code into an executable and pushed into the device using ADB. The binary is placed inside /data/local/tmp directory and executed from `adb shell`.

But i am unable to access the camera, is there any permission that i am missing? or does Android make it forbidden to use camera directly from an executable?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <camera/NdkCameraManager.h>

int main(){
    printf("Camera Manager\n");
    ACameraManager *cameraManager = ACameraManager_create();
    ACameraIdList *cameraIds = nullptr;
    ACameraManager_getCameraIdList(cameraManager, &cameraIds);
    printf("Number of camera %d\n", cameraIds->numCameras);
    //deleting the camera manager
    ACameraManager_delete(cameraManager);
    printf("Deleted the camera\n");  
}
```

The above code always print 0 as the number of camera

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely, your phone has a LEGACY camera. NdkCamera does not work with LEGACY camera, that's how you get `0` for **numCameras**. You don't need permissions to open the manager and read the idList.

But you cannot actually open a camera from command line: you cannot assign android.permission.CAMERA to a native binary. Also, you need a binder interface to work with camera, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/54224388/192373 *(that answer was written before the NDK r.20 when [NdkBinder](https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/group/ndk-binder) was released)*.

Comment: So permission can be only given to packages, not to binaries??

Comment: Android permissions can not be given to binaries, just like on any other OS access is controlled by user who runs the binary. If you run the binary as root, it will have the necessary permissions.