# Type declaration in header file ignored

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I am trying to access my phone's camera in c++ using the ndk. I copied the below code exactly, which does return a value for the person i copied it from: [How to access camera from natively compiled c++ binary in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57743462/how-to-access-camera-from-natively-compiled-c-binary-in-android)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <camera/NdkCameraManager.h>

int main(){
    printf("Camera Manager\n");

    ACameraManager *cameraManager = ACameraManager_create();
    ACameraIdList *cameraIds = nullptr;
 
   ACameraManager_getCameraIdList(cameraManager, &cameraIds);
    printf("Number of camera %d\n", cameraIds->numCameras);
    //deleting the camera manager
 
   ACameraManager_delete(cameraManager);
    printf("Deleted the camera\n");
```

However, it gives me 'ACameraManager was not declared in this scope' as an error. If i copy the declaration straight from the header file into the code, it accepts it.

It also gives an undeclared error for 'ACameraManager_create()' which i understand should be an opaque function pointer.

I cannot get the code to work. if i remove the opaque function, and copy all undeclared structs straight from the header into the code (before int main), it compiles and runs but gives a segmentation fault error after the first printf:

```
#include <camera/NdkCameraManager.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct ACameraManager ACameraManager;

typedef struct ACameraIdList {
    int numCameras;          ///< Number of camera device Ids
    const char** cameraIds;  ///< list of camera device Ids
} ACameraIdList;

int main(){
    printf("Camera Manager\n");

    ACameraManager *ACaminst;
    ACameraIdList *cameraIdList = nullptr;
 
    int ACameraManager_getCameraIdList(ACameraManager *ACaminst, ACameraIdList &cameraIdList);
    printf("Number of cameras %i\n",cameraIdList->numCameras);
    //deleting the camera manager

    void ACameraManager_delete(ACameraManager *ACaminst);
    printf("Deleted the camera\n");
}
```

I am new to C++, and i am coding this on my phone via the "c4droid" app. The compiler is g++ (i think), the c++ version is c++14. this seems to defy my understanding of header files. if defining the structures in the code declares them, why doesn't the header file declare them properly when included? Why does it tell me the opaque function is undeclared? I thought it was supposed to be that way.

Comment: Are you positive that the `NdkCameraManager.h` file is found by the compiler? Also, which minSdkVersion are you building for? (`ACameraManager_create`requires at least API level 24).

Comment: it's 21. My android version is 9 so i thought the api would be 28. Just for giggles i put cout<<__ANDROID_API__ in my code, and it returned 21. Thank you